# Why are procedural textures defaulting to pink?

Tags: texturing

I've searched throughout this forum and see that the reason textures are in pink is because "*the link to the texture file is missing*". I understand the whole external file linking workflow from other work I do.

What I don't understand is that I've not imported any textures which could have been lost. I'm using Blender (2.76) right out-of-the-box (and yes, I'm a complete noob), building from a blank start-up cube (no appends).

There appear to me to be default "textures" listed under 'type' such as 'clouds' and 'voronoi'. I've managed to apply a clouds 'type' with no additional external texture file to create a crude, but sufficient-for-now, wood effect.

What are the items listed under 'type'? Are they textures or some 'other thing' and if so, what is the 'other thing' (So I know what to look-up in the index of the noob guides I'm using)?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are not dealing with external textures, pink shows up when the texture is not mapped properly.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. You've clarified a lot, strangely. I now know what to study.

Comment: Please edit your question and add screen captures of how you set up your texturs and your material. If possible upload a file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Apologies. I don't know what you mean by 'edit your question'. [Frantically looks for a 'mark as answered' button.]

Comment: At the bottom left of your question there are 4 otpions: share, edit, close, flag... use the edit link, so you can edit your question and add more information.

Comment: Thank you, though the question is answered as far as I'm concerned: "the texture is pink because it's not mapped properly".I'm such a noob, I don't think it would be a good idea to extend the question to mapping. I need to go study rather than take anyone's time up with it here. I'm not even clear, yet, when it's a 'material' and when it's a 'texture'.

Comment: The whole point of blender.stackexchange is for newbies, ask and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the default color of the procedural texture as shown in the image.
Property panel > Texture tab > Influence Section.

[image]

> There are many types of texture in the list. Most of them are
> classified as procedural. Procedural is just a way of saying "code generated
> textures" ... instead of the regular images made from a bunch of pixel (RGB)
> information.
>
> The power in procedural map is that it can be applied in many ways
> (as a mask or as a texture), mixed with other procedural textures to
> form new ones... and this is just two of the many benefits.
>
> The image / Environment map type texture is the only two types that isn't consider procedural.

Comment: Thank you Hawkenfox. When I asked if the textures in the list were some 'other thing', I was wondering if they were some sort of alpha channel (mask). Interesting to find they can be used either way.